# Why would we be missing one request parameter in jQuery HTTP GET request?

Tags: jquery

On a page of our web site we have a form with four input fields for four four-digit parts of a credit card number.
On form submit these fields are used to create a GET request to our server via jQuery, and for 99.999% of our customers this works just great.

But there is one customer who has problems when submitting this form.  In the nginx log we have only the three last request parameters - from **CardNumber2** to **CardNumber4**, with **CardNumber1** missing.  (While a normal request looks like ...**&CardNumber1=4111&CardNumber2=1111&etc**, this request looks like ...**&CardNumber2=1111&CardNumber3=**...)

What could cause this field to be skipped on submit? There is no absolutely difference between this field and three other credit card fields.
Client browser has the following user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
```

(This is is just the latest 15.01 FF on Win x64).

We have a screenshot of this page on the client's computer with absolutely normal digits inputted into all four credit card fields.

Could some security software or browser plugin remove CardNumber1 from request?

Comment: are those fields mandatory and sent via POST? where I'm getting is that the client may not have filled every field, even if he/she sent the screenshot, don't believe everything you see. And finally, is it worth spending a lot of time for such a small percentage of fail, I mean, direct the client to use a different browser.

Comment: I suppose that whether it is worth or not does not depend on an author's opinion. Rather on a his boss' one.

Comment: You really need to setup a cloned environment and do some testing, you can't always rely on the clients machine being correctly setup.

Comment: All these fields are mandatory. Their presence is validated on client by JS. JS is definitely enabled, as site is completely unfunctional without it. And JS gathers all these fields into request and performs GET request.

Comment: For us all clients are money, sometimes rather big, so me are trying to fix all possible problems. And also we cannot accurately measure the severity and rarity of this bug, as this client sent as a mail with this bug, but who knows how many of people have simply failed to create an order and decided to use some of our competitors.

Comment: Our clients are simple web users, so all that we can reproduce, I think, is the same version of web browser. I have tried FF 15, and of course was unable to reproduce the bug)

Comment: We can tell to this specific user to try to use another browser, but we should find the reason of this strange behaviour, as we cannot say to any user of FF 15 to switch to another browser:)

Comment: Are there a lot of other parameters in GET? There is a limit for GET length so maybe this is the problem?

Comment: There are many other parameters, but limit for GET request length is not reached, we have recentrly increased it up to 5 Kb. And there are similar requests from the samу page with similar data which are much more longer and which are executed normally. And also parameter **CardNumber1** is in the middle of request string, and other parameters around it are ok.

Comment: Just a crazy idea :) Maybe customer by himself removed this field from form - using for example firebug plugin for firefox. I don't know how smart that customer is so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @JurisVaiders Everything can be, but this user have written a letter to us saying that he was unable to create a order so he is moving to our competitors. I think, if at the same time he has removed this field by firebug - he has some serious mental problems like double identity :) I will try now to reproduce the scenario you've described.

Comment: Is it possible that an old version of the JS is being cached?

Comment: @jholloman, this is possible, I think, but I'm not sure that there ever was any version of js that ignored CardNumber1 field.

Comment: RE cached older assets: you can trick a browser into using an updated asset by appending a GET parameter to the asset like such as `<script … src="script.js?cache=load_new>"` (then it thinks you're referencing a new/different file).

Comment: @jacob, seems like user has FF 15.

Comment: @MikhailBrinchuk, oh wow ^^, I could've sworn I read he was having trouble in IE…

Comment: Is it possible to use firebug or fiddler to analyse the content of what the browser is sending. Perhaps not if they have gone to your competitor.

Comment: @chrisp_68, unfortunately this is impossible, this is our client's machine, and we as usual website where he purchases some service cannot use these tools.

Answer (score 0):

What does your code on the front end look like for grabbing the form values? Also what backend language are you using to receive the form values and what does it look like. If you have already seen 3 of the form inputs populate to your database or where ever your sending the information, then I would guess you maybe having backend issues possibly.